# Passing Node.js SQL connection to multiple routes

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js

Here are the app.js, users.js and user.js routes of a node application I am building. As you can see I am connecting to the SQL DB in each route, and this is not ideal. I have tried passing the connection to different routes at least 3 different ways based on examples online. I have failed multiple times.

Please advise as to the best way to pass this connection. I am sure there are other errors in my code, so anywhere I can improve I would appreciate feedback. It is currently working, kinda. You can sign up login with auth and submit a bid working version [here](https://pure-sierra-43583.herokuapp.com). But the server times out and the app crashes a lot.

**APP.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local'),Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
async = require('async');
SchemaObject = require('node-schema-object');
var app = express();

// This should make our db available in all views.. 
/*  wrapped our database object into every request .*/
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    //req.conn = conn;
    req.app = app;
    //req.db = db;
    // handle_database(req,res);
    next();
});

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var classes = require('./routes/classes');
var bids = require('./routes/bids');
//var students = require('./routes/students');
var clients = require('./routes/clients');
//var reviews = require('./routes/reviews');
var instructors = require('./routes/instructors');
var companys = require('./routes/companys');
//var instructors = require('./routes/instructors');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

// Connect-Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);

  if(req.url == '/'){
    res.locals.isHome = true;
  }
  next();
});





// Makes the user object global in all views
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  app.use(flash());
  // put user into res.locals for easy access from templates
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;

    if(req.user){
      res.locals.type = req.user.type;


    if(req.user.type == 'company'){
      res.locals.isCompany = true;
    } 

    if(req.user.type == 'client'){
      res.locals.isClient = true;
    } 
  }
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/classes', classes);
app.use('/bids', bids);
//app.use('/students', students);
app.use('/clients', clients);
//app.use('/reviews', reviews);
app.use('/instructors', instructors);
app.use('/companys', companys);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

**users.js route**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var db = require('../database');
var returnedPw;
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');


var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'nunyabusiness',
    user : '',
    password : '',
    database : ''
});


// Include User Model
var User = require('../models/user');
// Include Student Model
var Client = require('../models/client');

// Include Instructor Model
var Company = require('../models/company');

router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('users/signup');
});

router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
    // Get Form Values
    console.log('starting post and making new user');

    var first_name      = req.body.first_name;
    var last_name       = req.body.last_name;
    var street_address  = req.body.street_address;
    var city            = req.body.city;
    var state           = req.body.state;
    var zip             = req.body.zip;
    var email           = req.body.email;
    var username        = req.body.username;
    var password        = req.body.password;
    var password2       = req.body.password2;
    var type            = req.body.type;

    // Form Field Validation
    req.checkBody('first_name', 'First name field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('last_name', 'Last name field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email must be a valid email address').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('users/signup', {
            errors: errors,
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            street_address: street_address,
            city: city,
            state: state,
            zip: zip,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            password2: password2
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            email: email,
            username:username,
            password: password,
            type: type
        });
        console.log('calling post to database file to receive new user:' + newUser)

        // THIS IS WHERE WE ARE POSTING THE NEW USER TO THE DATABASE!!!
        //db.registerUsers(newUser);

        User.saveUser(newUser);

        var newClient = new Client({
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            address: [{
                street_address: street_address,
                city: city,
                state: state,
                zip: zip
            }],
            email: email,
            username:username
        });
        if(type == 'client'){
            //User.saveClient(newUser, newClient, function(err, user){
            //  console.log('Client created');
            ///}); works but replacing w sql
        } else {

        var newCompany = new Company({
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            address: [{
                street_address: street_address,
                city: city,
                state: state,
                zip: zip
            }],
            email: email,
            username:username
        });  

            console.log('calling sql save..');
            //db.postUsers(newUser, newClient);

        }

        req.flash('success','User added');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});


<!--//// -USER AUTH SECTION- \\\\--!><!--//// -USER AUTH SECTION- \\\\--!><!--//// -USER AUTH SECTION- \\\\--!>

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});


router.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect:'/', failureFlash:'Wrong Username or Password'}), function(req, res){
    req.flash('success','You are now logged in');
    // it appears that the pipes re crossed and the type is being set as the username. need to check our model and post
    var usertype = req.user.type;
   // res.redirect('/'/*+usertype+'s/classes' */);
    console.log(user + 'hail Mary');
    res.redirect('/' /*, { "results": user } */ );
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done ) {
            console.log('in users the username is ' + username)
            connection.query('SELECT password FROM t_user WHERE username = ?', username, function(err, user) {
                console.log(user +'got user')
                parseResults(user, done);
            });// end query

        function parseResults(user, done) {   
            Object.keys(user)[0];
            var key = Object.keys(user)[0];
            user[key]; 
            var storedPw = user[key];
            for(var i in storedPw){
                returnedPw = storedPw[i];
            }

            console.log('returnedPw is defined here ' +returnedPw);
            movePw(returnedPw,  done);
        }// end function

        var candidatePassword = password;

        function movePw (returnedPw, done) {
            if (returnedPw ) {
                User.comparePassword(candidatePassword, returnedPw, function(err, isMatch) {
                    if (err) return done(err);
                    if(isMatch) {
                       user = username;
                       return done(null, user);

                    } else {
                        console.log('Invalid Password');
                        // Success Message
                        req.flash('failureFlash','User Access Denied. False Password');
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
                    }
                });  
            }
            else {console.log('return PW not defined')}
        }

    }// end outer function ?

));//end passport

// Log User Out
router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    // Success Message
    req.flash('success', "You have logged out");
    res.redirect('/');
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
      return next(); 
    }
  res.redirect('/')
}

module.exports = router;
```

**User.js**

```
var SchemaObject = require('node-schema-object');
var db = require('../database');
var connection  = require('express-myconnection');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'sm',
    user : 'an',
    password : '',
    database : 't'
});

// User Schema
var user = new SchemaObject({
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        bcrypt: true
    },
    type:{
        type:String
    }
});

var User = module.exports = user;

// Fetch All Classes
module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

// #1 IN THE LOGIN PROCESS THIS IS FIRST FUNCTIO CALLED
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username){
    console.log('in our user model, attempting to fetch user...')

    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    console.log('returning username function...')
    console.log('making sure we got the username ' + username)
    var query = {username: username};
    connection.query('SELECT ? FROM t_user',query, function(err, results, query) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if(!err) {
            console.log('um ok, heres your query results i guess.. ' + results)
            indexPage.receiveResults(results);
        }
    });
};

// Recieve Results
exports.useReceiveResults = function (results) {
        res.render('index', { "results": results });
};

// Save Client
module.exports.saveClient = function(newUser, newClient, callback){
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, 10, function(err, hash){
        if(err) throw errl
        // Set hash
        newUser.password = hash;
        console.log('Client is being saved looking for db');
        async.parallel([newUser.save, newClient.save], callback);
        return;
    });
}

// Save User
module.exports.saveUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, 10, function(err, hash){
        if(err) throw errl
        // Set hash
        newUser.password = hash;
        console.log('Client is being saved looking for db');
        //async.parallel([newUser.save, newClient.save], callback);

        connection.query('INSERT INTO t_user SET ?',newUser, function(err, results, newUser) {
        //connection.release();
            if(err) console.log(err + 'darnit');
            if(!err) console.log('data recieved by database...');
        });
        return;
    });
}


// Save Company
module.exports.saveCompany= function(newUser, newCompany, callback){
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, 10, function(err, hash){
        if(err) throw errl
        // Set hash
        newUser.password = hash;
        console.log('Company is being saved');
        async.parallel([newUser.save, newCompany.save], callback);
    });
}

// Compare password   
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, returnedPw, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, returnedPw, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a file

#### db.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var settings = require('./settings.json');
var db;

function connectDatabase() {
    if (!db) {
        db = mysql.createConnection(settings);

        db.connect(function(err){
            if(!err) {
                console.log('Database is connected!');
            } else {
                console.log('Error connecting database!');
            }
        });
    }
    return db;
}

module.exports = connectDatabase();`
```

This will create a singleton db connection;
Also as you can see, you could have your mysql settings in another file

#### settings.json

```
{
    host : 'sm',
    user : 'an',
    password : '',
    database : 't'
}
```

That way you have everything more organized.

Then on each of your files where you want to make a query you just have to require the db.js file

```
var db = require('./db');
```

and with that var call the query function. For instance in your User.js file, the query to get the user by name would be something like:

```
var db = require('./db');

db.query('SELECT ? FROM t_user',query, function(err, results, query) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if(!err) {
        indexPage.receiveResults(results);
    }
});
```

Comment: The overall pattern is solid, but I'd use connection pooling instead of a single connection (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections). As a small side note, I've also found that it's more flexible to create simple JS files for config than JSON files (which lack comments and are not dynamic)

Comment: I have been working on this app using these patterns. github is up and tutorial on my website www.seanquinndesign.com/blog/index.html